# Compare files in PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, difference

I'm working with PySpark and I need to compare the content of two files - to do a diffcheck.
So I divided my tests into 2:

1. I'm taking joined columns between the files, and checking if the records are the same
2. I'm taking the unique columns from each file, and saves them (to test manually)

The first step is done by taking

```
joined_columns = set(tbl1.columns).intersection(set(tbl2.columns))
joined_columns_str = str(joined_columns)[1:-1].replace("'", "")

tbl1_set = spark.sql("SELECT " + joined_columns_str + " FROM tbl1")
tbl2_set = spark.sql("SELECT " + joined_columns_str + " FROM tbl2")

sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl1_set " \
          "EXCEPT " \
          "SELECT * FROM tbl2_set "
different_records = spark.sql(sql)
```

However, in these files I have map columns - so I'm getting this error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot have map type columns in DataFrame which calls set operations(intersect, except, etc.)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it and get only the un-identical records?
I thought about using udf, but couldn't find how to work with it on "select * ", only when referring a specific field...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try to `explode` the map ? You will have key/value column instead, and you can compare each element of the map.

Comment: Hi @Steven, to do so I'll need to address specific columns, won't I...? how can I explode a column only if it's a map?